# Netbeans 7.2.1 + XAMPP

Tags: netbeans, xampp, phpdoc

I develop primarily remotely using NetBeans 7.2.1.  I'm beginning to see that NetBeans can use a local php interpreter for more than just running the code locally.  I stumbled across loads of information regarding phpDoc, which I'm currently trying to get working properly.

What other benefits or otherwise neat tricks can be done by using NetBeans with XAMPP that I couldn't do when uploading on save to a remote server?  I'm getting the idea that I'm missing out on all sorts of neat stuff.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1):

It's always good to have a local server in case your internet provider dies, or in case you run out of wifi..
The environment that I use for web development is, local xampp, netbeans, and svn.

When I have major changes I commit changes to my repo in assembla, and then update in the server. You can always use a more sophisticated cvs, for synchronous update of the server (git for example, using bitbucket free hosting).

Comment: Are there any major NetBeans features that I'm missing out on by using a remote servers as opposed to XAMPP?  Or is it merely a matter of network speed/connectivity?

Comment: Yes, as I see it, it's only a matter of internet connectivity. In fact a lot of people develop in the environment you are presenting here